# What directory do applications store edits made to a document?

Tags: linux, windows, macos

In Windows, OSX and Linux based operating systems, when a user makes an edit to any document using any program, is there a specific directory that edit will get saved to?

I am thinking maybe it's the following but I'm not sure.

**Windows**

```
C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Temp (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

**Linux**

```
/tmp
```

Comment: No there isn't a specific directory. Every program does this differently.

Comment: I see and is there a way to determine which directory a specific program is temporarily storing each edit?